# MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Help me pls.
I have 3 tables:

**users**
id rating

**posts**
id_post rating id_author

**photos**
id_photo rating id_user

Need query for update users rating based on formula: avg(users posts ratings) + avg(user photos ratings).
Tryed this but works only if user have and posts and photos. If user have photos, and no posts then ratings become 0:

```
UPDATE users U
                inner JOIN
                 (select id_user, avg(rating) as avgrating
                    from photos P
                    group by id_user
                 ) P
                 on U.id = P.id_user
               inner JOIN
                 (select author_id, avg(rating) as avgrating_posts
                  from posts PS
                    group by author_id
                 ) PS
                 on U.id = PS.author_id
                SET
        U.rating = (
                                            P.avgrating +
                                            PS.avgrating_posts 
                                         )



UPDATE users SET
        rating = (
            ( SELECT AVG(rating) FROM photos
                        WHERE photos.id_user = users.id AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0 AND date_published > 0 ) +
            ( SELECT AVG(rating) FROM posts
                        WHERE posts.author_id = users.id AND published_at > 0
```

) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left` join for your inner queries, so if there are no associated records found for a user a null value will be returned.

```
UPDATE users U 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT author_id, 
                          AVG(rating) AS avgrating_posts 
                   FROM   posts PS 
                   GROUP  BY author_id) PS 
               ON U.id = PS.author_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_user, 
                          AVG(rating) AS avgrating 
                   FROM   photos P 
                   GROUP  BY id_user) P 
               ON U.id = P.id_user 
SET    U.rating =  COALESCE(P.avgrating,0) + COALESCE(PS.avgrating_posts,0)
```